# Where to find available color schemes in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, vim, color-scheme

I Look to change the color scheme of my vim editor, then i search internet and they ask me to edit the ***.vimrc*** file, and i changed it like this,

> colorscheme morning

it worked but what i want to know is the other color schemes that i have in my system,still i don't find a useful link on the internet, can anyone suggest me a way that i can find the other color scheme options that i have in my system ? because this color scheme is bit annoying to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the colorschemes in your file system. However it is tricky, because the color scheme could be located in different places.

I don't think there is a vim command, list all available colorschemes on your system. However, if you just want to see the list, you can use the auto-completion feature in command line. Just do:

```
:colorscheme (space)
```

Then press `<Tab>`, as other vim commands, vim will list all possible parameters, in this case, all available colorschemes will be shown.

Same way, if you type

```
:set (space) <Tab>  "all options will be shown
:call (space) <Tab>  "all functions will be shown
....
```

they would be long lists however. ;-)

Comment: CTRL-D also works in place of Tab for a different view of the list. Still not an easy way to retrieve it though.

Answer (score 2):

for my computer(ubuntu 16.04), i found the available color schemes for vim in

> /usr/share/vim/vimNN/colors/

Comment: For WSL ubuntu this is the exact path.

Answer (score -1):

The default path for vim color schemes in Peppermint Ten (based on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) is:

```
/usr/share/vim/vim80/colors
```